# Error retrieving a list of data from firebase firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a shopping app where i need to save a list of objects, the saving into firestorm is working fine but upon getting the data, it keeps crashing and throwing an error, if anyone could help, Thank you in  advance

- This is a screenshot of firestorm and how is data saved
  [image]

- Error thrown

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.shoppingapp, PID: 2110
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.example.shoppingapp.models.CheckoutModel
```

- This is how i'm saving data into firestore

```
                Map<String,Object> paymentMap = new HashMap<>();
                paymentMap.put("total",String.valueOf(itemsTotal));
                paymentMap.put("items",list);

                firebaseFirestore
                        .collection("Orders")
                        .document(uniqueID)
                        .set(paymentMap)
```

- This is how i'm trying to retrieve data

```
   firebaseFirestore
                .collection("Orders")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for(DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                            List<CheckoutModel> map = (List<CheckoutModel>) document.get("items");
                            String totalPrice = document.get("total").toString();

                            // TESTING BY GETTING PRODUCT ID
                            // it throws exception here
                            textView.setText(map.get(0).getProductID());
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: did you try to add an exception to the logs in `onFailure`? Never ignore errors in coding

Comment: Can you provide logs or error messages?. It would help deducing the problem

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have edited the code please take a look ,Thank you

Comment: @REX I have edited the code please take a look ,Thank you

Comment: Please also edit your question and show us the content of your `CheckoutModel` class. Besides that, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10) will help. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things can be done,

1. Instead of mapping the whole list, try iterating through document and map one object at a time.
2. Secondly, In your checkOutModel give initial values to all of your variables. Mapping gives error if variables does not have initial values.
   Like, instantiate string variables with " ", and numeric variable with 0 or 1.

Comment: Yes i have done it and it worked , i have used the first method .